RTSP stream to web
I am trying to render a RTSP stream from my cam, I have tried using RTSPToWeb, when I open the RTSPToWeb proxy server, I only see MSE working (for other streams, I can see the four formats that the library gives as output).
After reading the docs, I´ve tried creating the url for the MSE stream that I get from RTSPToWeb but it doesn´t render it on my web app.
Found this in the doc for RTSPToWeb:
MSE
/stream/{STREAM_ID}/channel/{CHANNEL_ID}/mse?uuid={STREAM_ID}&channel={CHANNEL_ID}

ws://127.0.0.1:8083/stream/{STREAM_ID}/channel/{CHANNEL_ID}/mse?uuid={STREAM_ID}&channel={CHANNEL_ID}

I tried constructing the url like that to no success.
My config looks like this:
{
  "server": {
    "debug": true,
    "http_debug": false,
    "http_demo": true,
    "http_dir": "web",
    "http_login": "demo",
    "http_password": "demo",
    "http_port": ":8083",
    "https": false,
    "https_auto_tls": false,
    "https_auto_tls_name": "",
    "https_cert": "server.crt",
    "https_key": "server.key",
    "https_port": ":443",
    "ice_servers": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"],
    "log_level": "debug",
    "rtsp_port": ":5541",
    "token": {
      "backend": "http://127.0.0.1/test.php"
    },
    "defaults": {
      "audio": true
    }
  },
  "streams": {
    "pattern": {
      "channels": {
        "0": {
          "url": "rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264",
          "debug": false,
          "audio": true
        }
      },
      "name": "pattern"
    }
  }
}

In my react app, I add the url like this:
<Camera src="http://localhost:8083/stream/pattern/channel/0/mse?uuid=pattern&channel=0" />

It doesn´t render it

Its not clear what your Problem is, it doesnt Render. Is very unclear Infos. When you get the mse did U implement the js mse Part ?
